# Magento: case/tiered pricing and being able to break out of case and price for individual skus

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I am just looking for some ideas, we have a client that wants pricing by case which gets special pricing then if you are buying individually. so lets say the case quantity is 12 and you buy 3 cases, we could easily setup a tiered pricing scenario, if quantity > 12 price is x,  if quantity is > 24 price is x, if quantity > 36 price = x. The problem is lets say they wanted to buy 3 cases and 3 individual skus. Magento's tiered pricing will not work with this because everything over 36 will have the same price.

We would of just created a case quantity attribute and put that as a dropdown menu where it would list 12, 24, 36 and when they choose that, it populates the quantity field. Programmatically or out of the box, does anyone think there is a way to say if the user buys 36 the price per unit = x, if the customer buys 39, the price is x for 36 and x for 3?

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to offer your individual SKU as a Simple Product with no tier pricing, then create a Bundle product of 12 SKUs and offer that with your tier pricing.  You can force the Bundle Item to be sold in increments of 12

That way you're still selling the same SKU, and the customer can add 3 bundles and 3 individuals = 39 products.

A bit of a pain having two product pages, but is you use the Upsell block with an Qty field and Add to Cart button on the product detail page, that could reduce that hassle for the customers.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, I haven't thought about this way, I will see how it goes when I set up a test. I have tried a couple other variations but haven't thought about using a bundle.

Comment: I'm still talking about solutions with my IA, not sure exactly what we are going to do quite yet